# itfoxtec-identity-saml2 is assertion encryption still not supported by the library?

Tags: encryption, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Is it possible to encrypt the assertion response with ITfoxtec Identity Saml2?

I had looked at the examples on GitHub, but it seems there is no encryption example there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authn response is encrypted in this sample: https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp

It is enabled by setting `saml2Configuration.DecryptionCertificate`:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp/Startup.cs#L34